# How to acess router's admin password if we have access to its telnet?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, passwords

Ok, so I recently discovered an old router lying around in my house,  **of Binatone, model no. bes460** . I tried resetting it, then tried all possible common admin username and passwords, with nothing working. Then, **I tried RouterSploit, and got to know the telnet username and password. Now I do have access to its terminal**, and managed to scavenge the wireless password, but have no clue as to where the admin password might be stored in. I attached a few screenshots that I felt might be relevant, and a bit of information I could scavenge.

Specs:

1. RicherLink RL-ANS5004.
2. Runs on OpenWRT

[image: Root Directory][image: root/tmp directory. This is where the telnet defaults me to.]
(Two different OSes because I've dual-booted my system)

EDIT: Added login page if it would make you help recall which company this router might belong to.
[image: Router Login Page]

EDIT: Guys I don't have access to the admin page because I don't have admin credentials, I just have telnet access, so whatever I am looking for would have to be found in the terminal itself. I obviously can't use the UI. So please stop suggesting that. If you don't mean that, please clarify as I can't understand what you mean.

Comment: I do not know that router, but any of the many routers I have used over the years have the Admin Password and Password Change routine in the Administration, Setup or Security tabs.  Are any like tabs available to you? I could not tell from the screen shot.

Comment: @John I think I do. I will attach a screenshot of the root directory soon if it would help you.

Comment: There should be a configuration screen for the router. That is what we need.

Answer (score 1):

The password would be stored in some NVRAM variable, not a file. There probably is a tool in the firmware to dump all NVRAM variables.

If the router has any amount of security, the password will be stored as a hash, not plaintext, so you cannot retrieve it. However, if you can find out what kind of hashing method is used, you can (theoretically) replace the password.

---

Since in the most recent screenshot it says `luci` in the address bar, your router may in fact be running OpenWrt. You can check this by looking for `/etc/openwrt_release`. You could then follow OpenWrt reset procedures.

Comment: Yes it is using OpenWrt. The file exists. I'll look into OpenWrt and if your answer works I'll for sure tick it.

Comment: I can't really find a way to reset my router without SSHing into it, and I don't know the password, so :(

Comment: Do you know what hash OpenWrt may be using to store admin passwords

Comment: OpenWrt uses regular Linux facilities (`/etc/passwd`/`/etc/shadow`). However, the `ftp` user you’re currently using won’t be able to write to these locations.